# Installing any exe without having manual intervention using powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

How could i install any ".exe" without having any user action, means wherever the user interaction needed it should continue with the default selection (eg: license agreement) using powershell

any reference or links will help

[Discussed Below: Mostly wanted to install visual studio and visual studio related update]

Comment: With .exe you do mean setups right?

Comment: Not all steps has default action which allows to continue installation. For example some of license agreement steps require you to manually check the "Agree" checkbox before you can continue.

Comment: Depends on which installation software you use, every software uses its own individual buttons, etc. I don't think you will be able to make something for every software. What you could try is implementing a generic installation clicker for only ONE software (e.g. InstallShield).

Comment: @Jannik : yes, mostly i will be installing visual studio and visual studio related update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about Visual studio, and Microsoft product in general, you should look for unattended installation for example : [How to: Create and Run an Unattended Installation of Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee225237.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

For Visual Studio below command works:

```
 Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Installs\VS2013\vspremium.exe" -ArgumentList "/adminfile C:\Installs\VS2013\AdminDeployment.xml /passive /norestart" -Wait -NoNewWindow -PassThru
```

Also in the AdminDeployment.xml file you can make NoWeb="yes", it works otherwise as well.

```
<BundleCustomizations TargetDir="default" NoWeb="yes"/>
```